# On the interpretation of the phrase »in die Stadt gehen«

Tags: meaning

I am wondering which of the following interpretations is correct of the phrase »in die Stadt gehen«:

1. leave for the city, but not necessarily arrive in the city, for example, being halfway to the city
2. leave for the city AND arrive in it as well

---

In each of the following sentences, is it implied or not that he actually arrives in the city?

1. Er ist gestern in die Stadt gegangen.
2. Er ging gestern in die Stadt.
3. Er ist gerade in die Stadt gegangen.
4. Er geht morgen in die Stadt.

Comment: It might be interesting to know, why you assume 1. can be the case.

Comment: I have the impression you still assume there is an equivalent of English grammar sense of completed and continuing events in German grammar. **There isn't.** If you want to express an action is completed, you have to use a marker (particle or phrase) which says exactly that. It's the same as for continuing events, where you already used such a marker ("gerade".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase »*in die Stadt gehen*« implies arriving in the city. Otherwise it would be »*in Richtung Stadt gehen*«.

**To be more precise:**
»*In die Stadt gehen*« describes a movement towards town, and the person who is moving has the strong intention to really arrive there. But all you really know about this movement is from the perception that you can have at the start. So you know: He is definitely moving into the city, and he really wants to arrive there. But you don't know for sure, if he really did arrive or will arrive there, because you can't exclude, that something unforeseen has happened, that makes arriving impossible. But under normal circumstances he will arrive.

---

1. **Er ist gestern in die Stadt gegangen.**
   He went to town yesterday (and he arrived there).
2. **Er ging gestern in die Stadt.**
   He went to town yesterday (and he arrived there).
3. **Er ist gerade in die Stadt gegangen.**
   He just left to go to town.
   We don't know if he already arrived there. Either he already arrived there, or he still is on his way, and moving. But in second case he will arrive there (unless something unforeseen happens), because his goal is definitely to arrive there.
4. **Er geht morgen in die Stadt.**
   He will go to town tomorrow.
   Of course he didn't arrive there until now, because he even hasn't started moving. But he certainly will arrive there tomorrow (unless something unforeseen happens).

---

1. **Er ist gestern in Richtung Stadt gegangen.**
   He went towards town yesterday.
   We have no idea, if the town really was his target, so we don't know if he arrived there or somewhere else. Maybe he also passed through the town, and keeps moving to somewhere else. We don't know it. We only know: He left into the same direction where those people go who want to go to town.
2. **Er ging gestern in Richtung Stadt.**
   He went towards town yesterday.
3. **Er ist gerade in Richtung Stadt gegangen.**
   He just left towards town.
4. **Er geht morgen in Richtung Stadt.**
   He will go towards town tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use "in die Stadt gehen" in past tense, then it usually implies that you have really been there. The only example where we not yet know, if he will really arrive there is the sentence:

> er ist [gerade] in die Stadt gegangen

That means: he just started going there and probably has not arrived yet (but if nothing else happens, then for sure he will)...

Comment: Would you say that the sentence "Als er gestern in die Stadt ging, hatte er einen Unfall" is strange? (I actually FEEL it works better with "zur Stadt" but that should be irrelevant, as it isn't "proper" german) There might be a distinction depending on means of transportation as well.

Comment: Thats what I meant: we assume, that he arrived, if nothing else happened. This sentence is totally natural and not strange at all...

Comment: How about "Er geht die nächsten zwei Stunden in die Stadt" to mean that it takes two hours to walk there? (I do find that example weird myself and would think it means he stays there two hours. Still going to ask though, how about "zwei Tage", which might even mean going there two days in a row...)

Comment: That one simply means: within the next two hours he starts to go to the city. No exact time is given, just a time frame...

Comment: I disagree. That would be colloquial at best, in my opinion and I would never interpret someone saying this to mean that "Er geht innerhalb [der nächsten]/[von] zwei Stunden..."

Comment: Ok, so we disagree in that point. But somehow I don't get what you want to show here. My point is: without further information / unless stated otherwise we normally assume that one arrived / will arrive at town when using the phrase "in die Stadt gehen".

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker I have great difficulty answering this question and I assume you would get different answers from different people. Your examples i. and ii. mean the same thing and for iv. the question doesn't really make sense.

After some consideration I have come to the conclusion that both meanings are possible and not really distinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Leave for the city, but not necessarily arrive in the city, for example, being halfway to the city**

> Ich bin auf dem Weg in die Stadt

**2. Leave for the city AND arrive in it as well**

> Ich bin in die Stadt gegangen.